# What do different fields in accept field in HTTP request mean?

Tags: http, headers

What do different fields in accept field in HTTP request mean? I can understand the basics that through accept the client is telling the server what type of information it is waiting to receive, so for example:

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
```

This way the client will tell the server that it can understand three following formats:

- text/html
- application/xhtml+xml
- application/xml

But can someone tell me what this q values mean and that */*

Also if I have any flaws in my understanding - please tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

they are a [relative quality parameter](http://www.gethifi.com/blog/browser-rest-http-accept-headers)

they help specify the client preference as to which mime type they would prefer. 
this one is saying:
I prefer `text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;`
but I'll take `*/*` (anything) if thats all you have.

Answer (score 0):

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
```

One thing which massively confused me when first I was trying to understand this, is that in this context the comma is a higher level separator than the semi-colon, contrary to normal practice.

That is to say that this should be split out thus:

```
   Content Type              Preference Level
====================================================
1. text/html                 unspecified (implies 1)
2. application/xhtml+xml     unspecified (implies 1)
3. application/xml           0.9
4. */* (anything else)       0.8
```

I was reading the string, naturally in my head splitting it first on the semi-colons and secondly on the commas, then reading the explanation and not making any sense of it at all. I therefore thought that it would be helpful to explain that explicitly.